# Should we externalize validation strings & toString() method?

Tags: java, coding-style

I want to ask that if we should externalize string literals used in toString() implementations. Let me give an example :-

Suppose this is my toString() implementation :-

```
@Override
public String toString() {
 return "First Name: " + firstName + "," + "Last Name: " + lastName;
}
```

Here, should we externalize "First Name: " & "Last Name: " or not?

Another scenario is with Validation Strings. If I am creating Name Object with first and last name with first name can not be null. Then I put the following check in my constructor :-

```
if(firstName == null) {
 throw new NullPointerException("firstName is null");
}
```

Should we externalize "firstName is null" or not?

Thanks

Comment: What do you understand by externalization?

Comment: Can you give a hint about what made you think that this should be done?

Comment: String literals are external to the Object instance already.

Comment: Externalization => refactor a compilation unit such that strings used in the compilation unit can be translated to different languages

Comment: Do you mean; should they be defined in another class or as a constant?

Comment: @user1522820 I think you mean Internationalisation, Externalization is for serializing to bytes.

Comment: I guess OP is talking about Eclipse's externalize strings wizard.

Comment: It fairly rare to Internationalise the toString method as it usually used for debugging purposes only.

Comment: @adarshr Yes. I am talking about that.

Comment: Yes you should 'externalize' them. No you should not do it in a `toString()` method.

The `toString()` should return debug information. You should add another method named `getDisplayName()` or something similar that should return a localized String.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You really only need to do that if you want to allow debugging messages to be internationalized since `toString` shouldn't really be displayed to users

Comment: What about the messages we write while validating some parameter like:- if(firstName == null) {throw new NullPointerException("firstName is null");}

Comment: Should we externalize "firstName is null" or not?

Comment: @user1522820 Exceptions are on the same level as `toString()`, they should not be seen by users. If support personnel doesn't speak English, then you should. Most products I've seen do not attempt to internationalize those messages because the support team usually speaks English.

Comment: Well there's no reason that you can't use an exception to pass a localized error message. For instance: parsing a text field, you could catch NumberFormatException, add a localized 'Error parsing your information, please enter a number in the ___ field' string to your exception message, then pass it up to your prompt.

Comment: @Charles That is correct, you can use exception handling to display user messages. In that case, we usually have a base exception that has a `getUserFriendlyMessage` method. That method should be internationalized. I don't think you should ever use `getMessage()` of an exception and display to the user (unless the app is in debug mode). About your example, I really don't like checked exceptions. Some think it's OK to use them, many don't. http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?TheProblemWithCheckedExceptions

Comment: Agreed. Though, Checked vs Unchecked is an argument much larger than this question.

Answer (score 1):

Helpful link: http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Fconcepts%2Fconcept-string-externalization.htm

You might also want to check out this:
http://tika.apache.org/

So when tika gives you the language of a string, you should write a Java method like this:

```
enum languageToTransformString //create however many languages you want

public String toString(String lang)
{
    languageToTransformString = lang;
    switch languageToTransformString:
        case german:          
        firstNameText = "deutchName: ";  
        lastNameText = "deutchLastName: ";
        return new String(firstnameText + firstName + lastNameText + lastName);
         break;
        case eng:
       //do stuff

        firstNameText = "engName: ";  
        lastNameText = "engLastName: ";
        return new String(firstNameText + firstName + lastNameText + lastName);
        break;
        default:
        return new String("We don't support your language. Sorry.");

}
```

Comment: The variable firstNameText and lastNameText are supposed to be formatted in different languages. And I agree with the answer above, unless you're returning this to the user, in which case you'll want to use an enum like this.